# How to make a new incoming child page fade in and scale up as it transitions into the sceen

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, transition, user-experience

I'm trying to understand how to use AnimatedSwitcher in Flutter in order to create transition animations between two pages, what I want exactly is for the new page to fade in the screen slowly from the middle, and its opacity becomes clearer as the page scales up in order to finally fill up the screen.

I've tried multiple codes, but this one seems to work the closest to expected, except that the page that is being faded is the old one, at the same time the new one fades in the background. Which is not what I intend to have, I need the new one to fade in the screen as it scales up, here's a slowed-down GIF of this predicament.
[this is the current transition for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIdCA.gif)
here's the code:

```
 return AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 4000),
          transitionBuilder: (widget, animation) {
            return Stack(
              children: [
                FadeTransition(
                  opacity: animation,
                  child: widget,
                ),
                ScaleTransition(
                  scale: animation,
                  filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
                  child: widget,
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
          switchOutCurve: const Threshold(0),
          child: newWidget,
          //
        );
```

Comment: remove `Stack` and chain your both transitions so that the first is a parent for the second

Comment: See this output -  https://drive.google.com/file/d/16fVfCPFS7PkgxGdom_vu09LSb8rF5Oge/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to do the animation:

[Link to the output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MmrnN1AIv8SDcAIpYvPIwpGLso3CYKxG/view?usp=share_link)

#### 1. create the scale page transition

```dart
class FadeInAndScalePageRoute<T> extends PageRouteBuilder<T> {
  final Widget child;

  FadeInAndScalePageRoute({required this.child})
      : super(
          // change duration to suit your need
          transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => child,
          transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
            return ScaleTransition(
              scale: Tween<double>(begin: 0.5, end: 1.0).animate(
                CurvedAnimation(
                  parent: animation,
                  curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                ),
              ),
              child: FadeTransition(
                opacity: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
                  CurvedAnimation(
                    parent: animation,
                    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                  ),
                ),
                child: child,
              ),
            );
          },
        );
}
```

#### 2. How to use

```dart
Navigator.of(context).push(
  FadeInAndScalePageRoute(
    // replace with your page
    child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('New Page'),),
        body: Center(child: Text('My New Page'),),
      ),
    ),
);
```